# searching a column in a dataframe column with a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

i have the following dataframe named "anchor"

```
         tag         architecture    label
1        A1          ABC+DEF+GHI     dog
2.       A2          ABC+KLM+XYZ     cat
3.       A3          ABC+PQR+DEF     hen
4.       A5          ABC+DEF+KLM     pig
5.       B3          ABC+UVQ+XYZ     rat
6.       B1          ABC+XYZ+GHI     bat
```

i have  a list =c("ABC", "KLM", "GHI")

I need to search the architecture column of the dataframe for the names in my list  and create an output with the information in label column

the output should look like:

```
[1] ABC
dog cAt hen pig rat bat
[2] KLM
cat pig 
[3] GHI
dog bat
```

Answer (score 2):

We can split the `architecture` column with `separate_rows` and do a group by `paste`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
separate_rows(df1, architecture) %>%
        filter(architecture %in% list) %>%
        group_by(architecture) %>%
        summarise(label = str_c(label, collapse=' '))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  architecture label                  
#  <chr>        <chr>                  
#1 ABC          dog cat hen pig rat bat
#2 GHI          dog bat                
#3 KLM          cat pig
```

---

Or a `base R` solution with `aggregate` and `strsplit`

```
aggregate(ind ~ values, subset(stack(setNames(strsplit(df1$architecture, "\\+"), 
         df1$label)), values %in% list), paste, collapse=" ")
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(tag = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A5", "B3", "B1"), 
      architecture = c("ABC+DEF+GHI", 
"ABC+KLM+XYZ", "ABC+PQR+DEF", "ABC+DEF+KLM", "ABC+UVQ+XYZ", "ABC+XYZ+GHI"
), label = c("dog", "cat", "hen", "pig", "rat", "bat")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2.", "3.", "4.", "5.", "6."))

list <- c("ABC", "KLM", "GHI")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution.

```
sapply(vec, function(v) df1$label[grepl(v, df1$architecture)])
#$ABC
#[1] "dog" "cat" "hen" "pig" "rat" "bat"
#
#$KLM
#[1] "cat" "pig"
#
#$GHI
#[1] "dog" "bat"
```

The above code returns an object of class `"list"`. If you want a vector, assign that result to, for instance, `res` and then call `paste` on each of the list's members.

```
res <- sapply(<code above>)
sapply(res, paste, collapse = " ")
#                      ABC                       KLM                       GHI 
#"dog cat hen pig rat bat"                 "cat pig"                 "dog bat"
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
         tag         architecture    label
1        A1          ABC+DEF+GHI     dog
2.       A2          ABC+KLM+XYZ     cat
3.       A3          ABC+PQR+DEF     hen
4.       A5          ABC+DEF+KLM     pig
5.       B3          ABC+UVQ+XYZ     rat
6.       B1          ABC+XYZ+GHI     bat
", header = TRUE)

vec <- c("ABC", "KLM", "GHI")
```

Comment: I was about to post an absolutely identical solution Rui.You're too quick! :)